# Is it recommended to pass some data to scripts in `wp_enqueue_scripts`?

Tags: php, wp-enqueue-script, customization

I have on many occasions used `wp_enqueue_script` to pass some 'query variables' to scripts like this:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts(){
    $tempurl = urlencode( get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'somescript', get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/js/somescript.php?url=' . $tempurl );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'somescript' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

And I am just wondering if this is a 'best practice' or 'safe' to do, I don't see why it wouldn't be but I guess you never know until you ask. I'm just wondering what are the downsides of doing this, or even if there is an alternative/better way to do this.

I also notice if I pass more than 1 variable, only the first one will actually be retrievable in the script. Is there something I need to do to make that work?

Some advice would be great, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean with "passing more than 1 variable"? also, why are you placing all ur scripts into "somescript.php"? I don't understand why you are passing the blogurl at the end. Normally there are not problems with this approach, basically is used to keep the header or footer template as clean as possible.

Comment: I am just using the code above as an extremely generic example. What I mean by passing more than 1 variable is if this is in the URL: `?var1={somevar}&var2={anothervar}`. My question is not about using `wp_enqueue_scripts` specifically it is about using a PHP file and passing data with it inside that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) is the “WordPress way” to pass data from php to javascript. See [this post](http://ottopress.com/2010/passing-parameters-from-php-to-javascripts-in-plugins/) by Otto for more info.